# LilyPond: auto horizontal space for piano pedal

Tags: lilypond, engraving, keyboard-pedals

Is it possible to tell LilyPond to automatically add extra space for piano pedal symbols, so they don't overlap? If not, how to add the space manually?

Here is what I am trying to achieve:
[image: Three measures from the source score]

This is what I get:

[image: Same three measures as engraved by LilyPond]

You can see that the pedal symbols overlap in the second measure.

This is the code:

```
\version "2.22.1"
\language "italiano"

common = {
    \key sol \minor
    \time 4/4
    \tempo "Largro [Широко]"
}

right = \relative do'' {
    \common
    <fa, sib re>2 <sol sib sol'>2 (
    <fa re' fa>4 <sol do mib>2.)
    <fad la re>2~ 8 r8 r4
}

left = \relative do' {
    \common
    <sib, sib'>2 <mib, mib'>2 (
    <sib sib'>4 <do do'>2.)
    <<
        {
            \tempo \markup {\smaller \normal-text "(poco rit.)"}
            re'4 r s2
        } \\
        {
            re,8 (la' re la' re2)
        }
    >>
}

pedal = {
    s2 \sustainOn s2 \sustainOff \sustainOn |
    s4 \sustainOff \sustainOn s2. \sustainOff \sustainOn |
    s8 \sustainOff
}

\score {
    \new PianoStaff <<
        \new Staff = "right" \right
        \new Staff = "left" { \clef bass \left }
        \new Dynamics \pedal
    >>
    \layout {
        \context {
            \Voice
            \consists "Melody_engraver"
            \override Stem #'neutral-direction = #'()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you consider it satisfactory to move the notes themselves to avoid the overlap?

Comment: Sure, a workaround will do. Still would be curious to know if LilyPond can do it automatically. How to move notes?

Comment: FYI: I've added an addition solution to my answer that I think will work even better for what you're trying to do — the X-offset property.

Comment: Aside:  do you mean "Largo" rather than "Largro" in the tempo marking?

Comment: This is a typo, obviously.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Solution #1: X-offset property

Modify the `pedal` block with `\override SustainPedal.X-offset = 0.5`.

For example:

```
pedal = {
    s2 \sustainOn s2 \sustainOff \sustainOn |
    s4 \sustainOff \sustainOn
    \override SustainPedal.X-offset = 0 { s2. \sustainOff \sustainOn } |
    s8 \sustainOff
}
```

yields

[image: Solution 1 resulting image]

## Solution #2: extra-spacing-width property

Modify the `pedal` block with `\override SustainPedal.extra-spacing-width = #'(left-space . right-space)`.

For example:

```
pedal = {
    s2 \sustainOn s2 \sustainOff \sustainOn |
    \override SustainPedal.extra-spacing-width = #'(0 . 0) { s4 \sustainOff \sustainOn } s2. \sustainOff \sustainOn |
    s8 \sustainOff
```

yields

[image: Solution 2 resulting image]

## References

For more information, see the [LilyPond manual](https://lilypond.org/website/manuals.html). Specifically:

- [Grob Sizing](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/learning/outside_002dstaff-objects#grob-sizing) (extra-spacing-width)
- [SustainPedal object](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.20/Documentation/internals/sustainpedal) (X-offset; extra-spacing-with)

The key detail comes from the "Grob Sizing" section.

> By default, outside-staff objects are given a width of zero so that they may overlap in the horizontal direction.

Comment: Thank you! I think I can do one small correction to your code. After some experimenting, I realized that the left side number in `extra-spacing-width` is supposed to be negative. Setting it to `(5 . 5)` is equivalent to `(0 . 0)`.

Comment: Another interesting thing is that `extra-spacing-width = #'(0 . N)` and `\override SustainPedal.extra-spacing-width = #'(-N . 0)` produce the same result.